# Use whitespace in Windows command line parameters

Tags: java, windows, autoit, cmdline-args

My AutoIt script :

```
WinWaitActive("Open")
Send($CmdLine[1])
Send("{ENTER}")
```

I execute it from Java (passing a filepath to it):

```
String autoITExecutable = "C:\\filechooser.exe " + fileSource;
```

Name of file contains spaces, so it reads filename up to the first space and ignores the remainder. How do I correctly pass filepaths containing spaces as command line argument?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Name of files contains spaces, but it reads filename only for the first space and cuts filename.

As per [Documentation - Intro - Running Scripts](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/intro/running.htm):

> If you're passing strings with spaces, then you will need to escape these using "double quotes" in your commandline string.

Without, text after space will be contained by next array element (`$CmdLine[2]` in this case). Java example:

```
String autoITExecutable = "C:\\filechooser.exe \"" + fileSource + "\"";
```

Unprocessed command line (single string) is available as per `$CmdLineRaw` from receiving AutoIt script.

Comment: The assumption here is that filechooser.exe parses double quotes in its command line similarly to `CommandLineToArgvW` and VC++ `argv` parsing. It's a good assumption, but remember that Windows applications can really do whatever they want here. `CreateProcess` may parse the command line up to `"C:\\filechooser.exe "` if `lpApplicationName` is omitted, but the application itself just gets the unparsed string.

Comment: @eryksun Added statement on availability of unparsed command line string.