# How to put filename with spaces as parameter?

Tags: java, autoit, cmdline-args

When I run my AutoIt script for a filename without spaces ("filename.txt") it gets executed successfully. But when filename contains spaces ("File Name.txt") I get error "File not found".

Parameterized.au3 :

```
ControlFocus("Open","","Edit1")
ControlSetText("Open","","Edit1",$CmdLine[1])
ControlClick("Open","","Button1")
```

Execution from Java:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\Users\Screenshots\\Parameterized.exe" + " "
                + filePath);
```

`filePath` is passed as argument from another method :

```
filePath-> "C:\\Temp\\TMP\\TCs\\TC1\\Solution File.txt"
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use whitespace in Windows command line parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50625457/use-whitespace-in-windows-command-line-parameters)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take your file path into `"` so that your `exec` would look like:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\Users\Screenshots\\Parameterized.exe" + " "
                + "\"" + filePath + "\"");
```